# GLM and GAM package alternative to GRASP in R?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, spatial, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I am looking for the best package providing Generalized Linear Models (GLM) and General Additive Models (GAM) for spatial data. The most widely recommended ([GRASP](http://crantastic.org/packages/grasp)) is [no longer current in the repository](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/grasp/index.html).

Is there an alternative that is suggested, or would an archived version of this package still be the best option for these models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just rediscovered the [mgcv](http://people.bath.ac.uk/sw283/mgcv/) package, having revisited some literature that used it for their analyses. This is an actively maintained package by [Simon Wood](http://www.maths.bath.ac.uk/~sw283/).

The cran repository page can be [found here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mgcv/index.html).